# select column name from one table to other in linq using union

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code, where I'm union data from 2 tables

```
 var test =
                (from table1 in db.Products
                 select new UnionTable()
                 {
                     ProductNumber = table1.ProductNumber,
                     OrderNumber = 0,
                     Cost = table1.Cost,
                     Price = table1.Price,
                     Name = table1.Name,
                     Amount = 0,
                     Inventory = table1.Inventory
                 }).Union
                 (from table2 in db.OrderItems
                  select new UnionTable()
                  {
                      ProductNumber = table2.ProductNumber,
                      OrderNumber = table2.OrderNumber,
                      Cost = 0,
                      Price = 0,
                      Name = string.Empty,
                      Amount = table2.Amount,
                      Inventory = 0

                  });
```

the output is [image: output]

what I'm trying to do, is to fill the missing places with data. for example in name, I want all places where Product Number is 1, to be almond.
in price where Product Number is 1, all columns to be 10

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why are you using union? If there is a relation between Product and **OrderItems** then you can get it really easy.

Comment: with what? join?

Comment: Using **Include**

Comment: Union is for combining the (identical) rows from two different tables into one set of rows (# of rows = sum of # of rows from both tables) as if one table is on top of the other vertically. Is that what you want to do?

Answer (score -1):

You could always try something like this:

```
var test =
            (from table1 in db.Products
             select new UnionTable()
             {
                 ProductNumber = table1.ProductNumber,
                 OrderNumber = 0,
                 Cost = table1.Cost,
                 Price = table1.Price,
                 Name = table1.Name,
                 Amount = 0,
                 Inventory = table1.Inventory
             }).Union
             (from table2 in db.OrderItems
              select new UnionTable()
              {
                  ProductNumber = table2.ProductNumber,
                  OrderNumber = table2.OrderNumber,
                  Cost = 0,
                  Price = table1.Price == 0 && table1.ProductNumber == 1 ? 10 : table1.Price,
                  Name = table1.Name == string.Empty && table1.ProductNumber == 1 ? "Almond" : table1.Name,
                  Amount = table2.Amount,
                  Inventory = 0

              });
```

Not the most clean solution but it should do the job